# Anylogic: How to change agent graph presentation (stop appearing within GIS Map)?

Tags: graph, gis, anylogic, agent, presentation

On my Main tab in my Anylogic model I have a GIS Map. In another tab (from one of my agent populations), I have a graph (created from a time measurement within this agent). Whenever I run the model, the graphs of those agents are shown within the GIS Map (the same way the agents are placed on the map), as can be seen in the figure below. However, I want the graph to be shown next to the GIS Map (like the pyCommunicator and other parts shown above the map). Whatever I try (I placed the graph outside/inside the frame in the agent's tab), it stays within the GIS Map when running. Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you create the graphs in the main agent?

Answer (score 1):

Easier way is to create the graphs directly in the Main agent. For that, you should reference to the specific instance of the Terminal agent. For example `terminals(0).end.distribution`.

You also need to drag and drop Terminal agent into the Main.

Comment: Thanks for your tip! However when I do that, I receive this error: `Index 0 out of bounds for length 0` (while in other parts of the model `terminals(0)` does work)

Comment: Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. But I think I already have that (as can be seen in the picture in the question, the Terminal agent is just next to the pyCommunicator). Or is the Terminal agent I need to drag and drop something else?

Comment: Or if you already have in the Main agent, type in 5 there, instead of the option `Empty population. I will add agents later`

Comment: For that option I have `Loaded from database` (which are 5 records), because I also load their latitude and longitude from that database. In another agent tab, the `terminals(0)` does work, so I don't know why not now..

Comment: What if you add the agents on Main startup section? Like `Terminal add_terminals() `. This will create the empty agents before the simulation starts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241198/discussion-between-ella-and-yashar-ahmadov).